# OS X - How can a NSViewController find its window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I have a Document based core data app. The main document window has a number of views, each controlled by its own custom `NSViewController` which are switched in as necessary. I want each of these view controllers to be able to drop down a custom modal sheet from the document window. However because the views are separate and not in the `MyDocument` `nib` I cannot link the view to the document window in IB. This means that when I call

```
[NSApp beginSheet: sheetWindow modalForWindow: mainWindow modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
```

I’m supplying nil for `mainWindow` and the sheet therefore appears detached.

Any suggestions?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use `[[self view] window]`

Comment: I have tried this in the past - Xcode returns a Method '-view' not found (return type defaults to 'id') error

Comment: If `self` doesn't have a `view` method, then it's not an `NSViewController`.

Comment: Thanks Tom - that's my issue! I have a controller for the sheet that is instantiated by a subclassed NSViewController. Trouble is my sheet controller is subclassed from NSObject. To fix the issue I am now getting the window from my subclassed viewController using [[self view] window] and sending this to my sheet controller. Previously I was trying to get the window from my sheet controller

Comment: @AJ @TomDalling my `[self view]` returns <NSView: 0x6000001237a0> but `[[self view] window]` returns null, not sure what to do now.

Comment: I have the same issue as Jason

Comment: @Ethan It means that the view isn't in a window. The view either hasn't been added yet, or it has been removed.

Comment: @JasonMurray have you tried calling self.view.window in viewWillAppear of the NSViewController?

Answer (score 42):

Indeed, it's `self.view.window` (Swift).

This may be nil in viewDidLoad() and viewWillAppear(), but is set properly by the time you get to viewDidAppear().

Answer (score 2):

One issue with the other answers (i.e., just looking at `self.view.window`) is that they don't take into account the case that when a view is hidden, its `window` property will be `nil`. A view might be hidden for a lot of reasons (for example, it might be in one of the unselected views in a tab view).

The following (swift) extension will provide the `windowController` for a `NSViewController` by ascending the view controller hierarchy, from which the `window` property may then be examined:

```swift
public extension NSViewController {
    /// Returns the window controller associated with this view controller
    var windowController: NSWindowController? {
        return ((self.isViewLoaded == false ? nil : self.view)?.window?.windowController)
            ?? self.parent?.windowController // fallback to the parent; hidden views like those in NSTabView don't have a window
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your controller can get access to the [NSDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass, you can use [-windowForSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-BBCEFBHH)

Answer (score 0):

more about Tim Closs answer :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    self.view.window.title = @"title-viewDidAppear"; //this only works when and after viewDidAppeer is called
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear
{
    self.view.window.title = @"title-viewWillDisappear"; //this only works before and when viewWillDisappear is called
}
```